# Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities

Tags: selenium, protractor, bdd, selenium-grid, zalenium

Implemented the Zalenium in my protractor code. Live and dashboard view is popping out but when I tried to execute from zalenium it throwing the below error.

**[image: Console Error:]**

** Code**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because the browserName is named chromeOptions, just try chrome.

Comment: M, I have given as Chrome only. I have updated my screenshot in the question.